# Excel VBA: How do I add an item to a collection within a class?

Tags: class, excel, vba

I have a class that contains a collection of itself. (The top level class contains summary versions of the detailed instances in the collection.)

Currently the collection is a public variable because I haven't figured out all the details of working with private variables yet. I can fix that later.

**How do I add items to the collection? I am getting error 91 for missing object variables.**

Thanks for all prior help. I have been retooling my code to use classes more extensively, and it's really great how things are cleaning up.

Class cPE

```
Public PE_Details As Collection ' collection of cPE
Public PE_ID as integer
Public PE_ID_Index as integer

' Add to the detailed list of PE's
Public Function AddPEDetail(ByRef cPE_Detail As cPE)

    PE_Details.Add cPE_Detail    ' ERROR: Object variable or With 
                                 ' block variable not set

End Function
```

The module code that calls this is as follows:

```
Dim clsPE As cPE                ' Summary version of PE
Dim clsPE_Detail As cPE         ' A detailed PE
Dim i as Integer

Set clsPE = New cPE     ' This is the PE which will also contain a list of detailed PEs

' Add three instances of detailed cPE to the summary cPE object
for i = 1 to 3
   Set clsPE_Detail = New cPE

   clsPE_Detail.PE_ID = clsPE.PE_ID
   clsPE_Detail.PE_ID_Index = clsPE.PE_ID_Index
   'etc.

   clsPE.AddPEDetail clsPE_Detail  ' see above
next i
```

Comment: Where are you Setting PE_Details?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your cPE class add the method Class_Initialize and initialize your variables. As you have it now you never set PE_Details so it is null/nothing

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
 set PE_Details = New Collection 
End Sub
```